# multiple array to dataframe pandas

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy

So, I am iterating through a dictionary and taking a bunch of values out as a array -  Trying to make a Dataframe with each observation as a separate row.

```
X1 =[]
for k,v in DF_grp:
    date = v['Date'].astype(datetime)
    usage = v['Usage'].astype(float)
    comm = v['comm'].astype(float)
    mdf = pd.DataFrame({'Id' : k[0],'date':date,'usage':usage, 'comm':comm})
    mdf['used_ratio'] = ((mdf['used']/mdf['comm']).round(2))*100
    ts = pd.Series(mdf['usage'].values, index=mdf['date']).sort_index(ascending=True)
    ts2 = pd.Series(mdf['used_ratio'].values, index = mdf['date']).sort_index(ascending=True)
    ts2 = ts2.dropna()
    data = ts2.values.copy()
    if len(data) == 10:
        X1 =np.append(X1,data, axis=0)
        print(X1)

[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
[0,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3]
....
```

similarly, so the question is how do I capture all these arrays in a single DataFrame so that it looks like below:

```
[[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]] --- #row 1 in dataframe 
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]] --- #row 2 in dataframe
```

If the same task can be divided further ?
There are more thank 500K arrays in the dataset.
Thank You

Answer (score 3):

I hope below mentioned code helps you:

```
arr2 = [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]
arr3 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
arr4 = [0,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3]

li = [arr2, arr3, arr4]
pd.DataFrame(data = li, columns= ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5","c6", "c7", "c8", "c9"])
```

You can make it more dynamic by simply creating one temp_arr and appending that array to list. and creating data frame from generated list of arrays. Also, you can add name to columns(shown above) or avoid naming them(just remove column detailing). I hope that solves your problem

Comment: Edited the Question now, I have more than 500K arrays.

Comment: So to understand it correctly, you have 500, 000 arrays with each array having how many elements?

Comment: the number of elements are different but currently Im looking at just with len == 10.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an empty dataframe in second line i.e. below `X1=[]` with code `df = pd.DataFrame()`. Next, inside your `IF` statement pass the following after appending values to `X1`:

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.Series(X1)]).T
```

Or,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.NaN, index=range(3), columns=range(9))
for i in range(3):
    df.iloc[i,:] = np.random.randint(9)    # <----- Pass X1 here
df
#     0 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
# 0 4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0
# 1 7.0 7.0 7.0 7.0 7.0 7.0 7.0 7.0 7.0
# 2 8.0 8.0 8.0 8.0 8.0 8.0 8.0 8.0 8.0
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tried a similar approach but his breaks at the transpose with  --- 'Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects'

Comment: then declare a dataframe with known `shape` and `NaN` values. Later use `iloc` command to fill it. Cut the unnecessary rows later.

Comment: Could you provide an example, I did not get it.

Comment: check my modified answer. If you know the number of arrays beforehand then pass the value inside `index=range(NUMBER_OF_ARRAYS)`

Comment: Tried above now the error is   --   ' only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars'